# Electric field inside a cylinder capacitor, is it 0?

Tags: electric-fields, charge, capacitance, coulombs-law

I was just wondering if the electric field inside two cylinders with opposite charges is equal 0 even when the smaller cylinder is hollow as well. I understand if the smaller cylinder weren't hollow, but let's say a cable, the charge would only be distributed on the outside. But now having an empty smaller cylinder, is the situation affected in any way? How could I calculate the charge inside it?

Answer (score 3):

Draw a Gaussian surface inside the smaller cylinder. You'll find there is no enclosed net charge. Gauss's Law tells us that this means the electric field is zero inside.

The fact that there is no charge inside is actually made clearer if the smaller cylinder is hollow. If it is hollow, then inside the cylinder is simply vacuum, and in vacuum the charge density is zero by definition.

Edit: Thanks to The Photon for pointing out that this explanation needs some further work to be complete. In general, your electric field inside the smaller cylinder is $\mathbf{E} = \mathbf{E}(s,\phi,z)$, with $s$ as your radial coordinate, $z$ as the coordinate along the axis of the cylinder, and $\phi$ as the azimuthal angle in cylindrical coordinates. If we assume the capacitor is infinite, there is translational symmetry in the $z$ direction and therefore $\mathbf{E}$ cannot depend on $z$. There is rotational symmetry around the $z$ axis, which means $\mathbf{E}$ cannot depend on $\phi$. Ampere's law says that you can't have a component of $\mathbf{E}$ in the $\phi$ direction, so in general our electric field is $\mathbf{E}(s) = E_s(s)\mathbf{\hat{s}} + E_z(s)\mathbf{\hat{z}}$. It should be reasonably apparent that we must require $E_z(s) = 0$ without the introduction of some other charges somewhere else. Now Gauss's Law says that 
$$\begin{align} 
\oint_S\mathbf{E}\cdot d\mathbf{a} &= \frac{Q_{\textrm{enc}}}{\epsilon_0} \\
\oint_S E_s(s)\ \mathbf{\hat{s}}\cdot d\mathbf{a}&= \frac{Q_{\textrm{enc}}}{\epsilon_0}
\end{align}$$
which, with the choice of a convenient Gaussian surface where $Q_{enc} = 0$, gives $E_s(s) = 0$. This means that the electric field inside must be $\mathbf{E} = \mathbf{0}$.

Comment: Draw a gaussian surface between the plates of a parallel plate air-filled capacitor. Still no enclosed charge. But it doesn't prove there's no field between the plates. You need more than just no enclosed charge to show the field is 0.

Comment: Added a more rigorous explanation, thanks for pointing this out.